# Play store discoverability in related app's section missing

Tags: android

Description- Google play offers a related app's menu, when an app's listing is opened, there is a separate column/list which shows all the apps which are related to the app listing that is open.

The issue is we are not able to find our app in any other app's related app listing. It is visible in direct searches.

Our app is named 'Mindbreath breathing exercises'[Playstore link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meditation.hrv)

**Have a look at the below screenshots:-**
They've been taken from Pc for ease of viewing as more content can be seen in one shot, the results from an android device's playstore app are more or less the same (our app not visible)
[Our app listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miFxJ.jpg)

2. Our app's related apps window.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxlYY.jpg)

Now, we went through almost all the apps that are in our app's related app's window and tried to find our app. We could not. Refer to screenshots below-

3. The app which comes the first in our related app menu- "One Deep Breath: Breathing Exercises for Wellbeing". Attached is that app's related app's window, as you can see we did not find our app.
   [Related app's linked apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q5nA.jpg) As you can see we are not listed
4. The second related app- Breath Ball: The Stress Relieve Breathing Exercises. It's related apps menu-

[Related app 2's linked apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldAEH.jpg) Our app not listed

**Not adding more screenshots of other apps' related app menu, results will be the same.**

As mentioned, we tried going through almost all the apps related to us from two different accounts and hardware setups, but could not find our app.

We tried checking device compatibility from the console, we have not excluded any device from it. It shows around 8,000 device types compatible.

The app was launched at 21 September 2021.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this topic is not out of programming technical issues (off-topic).

Comment: it takes time to come related search

Comment: you can not do by ASO or other work

Comment: top editor choice comes first